# I need to get the post id for the first post of the current user in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have this so far

get_currentuserinfo(); $the_post = get_posts("author=" . $current_user->ID . "&posts_per_page=1"); $the_post = $the_post[0];

but I'm not sure how to get just the ID out of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_posts() will return an array of posts ordered by the date of publication, in descending order. So, with the code you posted, the first post in the array ([0]) will be the last post published by the author. If you really want the first post of the user, you can just add the order argument to the call (`&order=ASC`) to override the default.

I think the key for the ID is just "ID", so you can retrieve it with `$the_post = $post[0]['ID']`. But I have to admit I can't remember for sure and the documentation does not detail that, it could also be "post_id". You can do a: `print_r($the_post)` to check the keys of the returned array.

Comment: Wordpress Dokumenation @ http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts states: To access a post's ID or content without calling setup_postdata(), or in fact any post-specific data (data retained in the posts table), you can use $post->COLUMN, where COLUMN is the table column name for the data. So $post->ID holds the ID, $post->post_content the content, and so on. To display or print this data on your page use the PHP echo command, like so:

<?php echo $post->ID; ?>

Comment: @Cadoc: My mistake, you're right, it returns an array of post objects, so the ID would be retrieved with $the_post[0]->ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can write query like this way-

```
 $oldest_post_query = get_posts("post_type=post&numberposts=1&order=ASC");
 $oldest_post_id = $oldest_post_query[0]->ID;

 //print the post title
 <h1><a href="'.get_permalink( $oldest_post_id ).'" rel="next">'.get_the_title( $oldest_post_id ).'</a></h1>';
```